# Tensorflow._api.v2.train has no attribute 'AdamOptimizer'

Tags: python, tensorflow

When using

```
model.compile(optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

in my Jupyter Notebook the following Error pops up:

**module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'AdamOptimizer'**

Tensorflow Version: **2.0.0-alpha0**

---

Do you think the only possibility is to downgrade the TF version?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to be using an alpha release of Tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: @AKX , not really. Just downloaded the latest one and now struggling with the optimizer. Thought there is an easy workaround for this tbh.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```py
tf.train.AdamOptimizer() => tf.optimizers.Adam()
```

From https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/optimizers

Comment: basically, in your code, you need to replace tf.train.AdamOptimizer() with tf.optimizers.Adam()

Answer (score 26):

```
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Change the optimizer section for TensorFlow 2.1.0

Comment: Will this work fine if I'm using Tensorflow-gpu?

Answer (score 15):

I haven't tried 2.0 yet, but from what I've seen on the dev submit videos, you can use

```py
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
           loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
           metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 11):

```
tf.optimizers.Adam()
```

Is the way to go. No reason to downgrade.
There are lots of changes in tf 2.0 compared to 1.14.
Note that the parameter-names of Adam have changed, too. e.g. beta1 is now beta_1, check the documentation in Meixu Songs link.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error. I removed

```
tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
```

And I wrote

```
tf.optimizers.Adam()
```

Instead.

Answer (score 8):

It should be:

```
tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer()
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/AdamOptimizer

Comment: It helps if you put in a little more explanation.

Comment: This answer works well if you're trying to rerun a codebase which was written in tf 1.x which tf 2.x installed but I would recommend creating a virtual env with tf 1.x if possible as you'll need to make a lott of changes and .v1 to many functions

Answer (score 4):

It's a minor change in upgraded version.

Please use:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")
```

Thanks!