# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'AdamOptimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

The code:

```
model.compile(optimiser=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

The error:

---

```
AttributeError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-bf5e47e2458a> in <module>
----> 1 model.compile(optimiser=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), loss='binary_crossentropy', 
metrics = ['accuracy'])

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'AdamOptimizer'
```

Why is this code not working?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318273/tensorflow-api-v2-train-has-no-attribute-adamoptimizer)

Comment: this didn't work for me. although i found another way

Comment: import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

Comment: tf.compat.v1.disable_resource_variables()

Comment: these three lines solved the problem