# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'RMSPropOptimizer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, attributeerror

I am trying to run this [code file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QQGJIYKvkQJfUgjnNOcNSaBHPcAdtbud/view?usp=sharing) using google colab. Although I am getting some of the outputs but an error is showing up

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'RMSPropOptimizer'
```

I looked this problem up on stack overflow like most problems I face but there's no solution. Someone, please help me understand what's wrong with the code. I am completely new to TensorFlow.

**NOTE:** I would've pasted the whole code here but it's a 1400+ line code so I directly hyperlinked the file as people might get annoyed and moreover, by doing so this post will get very long. But if needed, I can edit the post and paste the whole code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct name is `RMSprop` and its located under `tf.keras.optimizers`. Therefore, please replace

```
optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(1e-4)
```

with

```
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(1e-4)
```

---

TensorFlow version: *v2.5.0*

Sources and more info:

- [TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/RMSprop)
- [Keras example](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/)
- [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/google/dopamine/issues/121#issuecomment-578522844)
- [Similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55492909/4202235)